# Copy a product to another view page in CodeIgniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-3

I'm making a website so users can add products to the website. Now I'm working on the product detail page. Everything works fine all the details of a product are getting echoed. But now I'm trying to make a button, When you click on that button, it must link to a new view page that I named 'cadeaupagina_ontvanger'and also it must copy the product and paste it on that view page. 
I don't know how to write this function in CodeIgniter,
Could someone help me?

This is the button from the details page:

```
<a href="<?php echo base_url() . 'Product/cadeaupagina_ontvangen/'.$product['user_id'];?>"> <button type="button" class="btn btn-default">Ik wil dit cadeau!</button></a>
```

Controller function details:

```
 public function details($product_id)
  {
    //load the Product_model
    $this->load->model('Product_model');
    //call function getdata in de Product_model
    $data['userdetail_list'] = $this->Product_model->getdata();
    $this->session->set_userdata("product_id", $product_id);

    //get product details
    $data['product'] = $this->Product_model->get_product_details($product_id);
    $data['products'] = $this->Product_model->selectProducts();

    //laad view
    $data['main_content'] = 'details';
    $this->load->view('details',$data); 
  }
```

Controller function cadeaupagina_ontvangen:

```
 public function cadeaupagina_ontvangen($product_id) {
    $this->load->model('Product_model');
    //call function getdata in de Product_model
    $data['userdetail_list'] = $this->Product_model->getdata();

    // get product details
    // if you want to pass data by url last param than use this
    if(!empty($product_id)){
    $data['product'] = $this->Product_model->get_product_details($product_id);
     }


    //if you want to pass data in session than use this
    //get session in current controller
    $product_id = $this->session->userdata("product_id");
    if(!empty($product_id)){
      $data['product'] = $this->Product_model->get_product_details($product_id);
    }


    $data['products'] = $this->Product_model->selectProducts();

    //laad view
    $data['main_content'] = 'ontvangen_cadeaus';
    $this->load->view('cadeaupagina_ontvanger',$data);
  }
```

cadeaupagina_ontvanger is the view page where I want to paste the same product.

model functions in Product_model:

```
 public function getdata()
    {
        $this->db->select('*');
        $this->db->from('users');
        $this->db->join('products','products.user_id = users.user_id');
        $query = $this->db->get();
        if($query->num_rows()>0)
        {
           return $query->result_array();
        }
    }

    public function selectProducts()
    {
        $query= $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM products");
        $result = $query->result_array();
        return $result;
    }



     /** Met deze functie kan je de product details ophalen via de $product_id  **/
    public function get_product_details($product_id) 
    {
        $arrReturn = array();
        $this->db->select('*');
        $this->db->from('products');
        $this->db->where('product_id', $product_id);
        $query = $this->db->get();
        $result = $query->result_array();
        if (!empty($result)) {
            $arrReturn = $result[0];
        }
        return $arrReturn;
    }
```

Comment: Add the previous controller methods in this controller.

Comment: Wait Ill edit my question and show what I had in my previous controller function

Comment: Check the controller function of details I edited my question

Comment: Copy this controller methods to cadeaupagina_ontvangen() and pass the product id as a session array.

Comment: How and where do I  pass the product id as a session array?

Comment: Hello are you there sir? i put $product_id in the cadeaupagina_ontvangen() method to. But when I click on the button, the product is not getting copied

Comment: Well You need to at least save the product_id in a session and recall it in your cadeaupagina_ontvangen() method. So create it in the original method. That way you can pass the product id or you can do it in the url.... Do you know how to use CI Sessions?

Comment: Yes. But how do I save the product_id in one of those sessions?

Comment: You read up on the Sessions Class in the Codeigniter User Guide of course... That way you learn... then if you are stuck - ask a question - but at least have a go at it.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this by 2 types:

**1. Send product id with controller url. Make sure in this url in the last add product id.**

```
<a href ='<?php echo base_url("Product/cadeaupagina_ontvangen/$product_id"); ?>'><button type="button" class="btn btn-default">Ik wil dit cadeau!</button></a>
```

**2. Or you can add the product id in the session as well in previous controller like this**

```
$this->session->set_userdata("product_id", $whatever_product_id);
```

Now in the current controller:

```
public function cadeaupagina_ontvangen($product_id='') {
    $this->load->model('Product_model');
    //call function getdata in de Product_model
    $data['userdetail_list'] = $this->Product_model->getdata();

    //get product details
    //if you want to pass data by url last param than use this
    if(!empty($product_id)){
      $data['product'] = $this->Product_model->get_product_details($product_id);
    }


    //if you want to pass data in session than use this
    //get session in current controller
    $pid = $this->session->userdata("product_id");
    if(!empty($pid)){
      $data['product'] = $this->Product_model->get_product_details($pid);
    }




    //laad view
    $data['main_content'] = 'ontvangen_cadeaus';
    $this->load->view('cadeaupagina_ontvanger',$data);
}
```

Comment: Hello, what now happens when I click on the button from the details page, it echo's all the products now when I get on the ontvangen_cadeaus view. I will edit my question and show all my code and hope you can fix it for me

Comment: I don't want it to echo all the products. I want to echo the same product from the details page and copy and paste it on the ontvangen cadeau's page with the same logged in user. So the next time when the same user goes to the ontvangen_cadeaus view page, the product should be there. So I guess I need to do something with the user_id from the products table and the user_id from the user table? Also I edited my question u can see my controller functions to now. Hope you can help me

Comment: So lets say I'm clicking on a certain product. It will link me to the details page. with a certain product_id .  for example this link: Product/details/96 , that means that I'm on a product details page with product_id = 96. Now on that page I want a button that links to another page and copy's that same product to that new view page. But only for that user that is logged in right now. he can only see that product when he goes to the ontvangen_cadeaus view page

Comment: But you say,I have to put the $product_id in the link? like this? :<a href ='<?php echo base_url("Product/cadeaupagina_ontvangen/$product_id"); Why do I have to do that? Don't I need to put the $product_user id in the link like this? : a href="<?php echo base_url() . 'Product/cadeaupagina_ontvangen/'.$product['user_id'];?>  because only the user that clicked on the button will see that product on the cadeaupagina_ontvangen view page

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/159651/discussion-between-anand-pandey-and-learningprogrammingphp44).